# CakePHP Custom CacheEngine and shell problems

Tags: shell, caching, cakephp, memcached, command-line-interface

I wrote my own cacheEngine for memcached as that's the extension I have installed on my server and not memcache, so I can't use the default memcache engine.

Now the engine is working fine when visiting the website, however. When I try to start a shell I get all sorts of Cache::Config errors, that I don't see when visiting the site.

```
PHP Warning:  Cache not configured properly. Please check Cache::config(); in APP/config/core.php in /home/ezra/sites/example.nl/cake/libs/configure.php on line 402

Warning: Cache not configured properly. Please check Cache::config(); in APP/config/core.php in /home/ezra/sites/example.nl/cake/libs/configure.php on line 402
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: prefix in /home/ezra/sites/example.nl/cake/libs/configure.php on line 410

Notice: Undefined index: prefix in /home/ezra/sites/example.nl/cake/libs/configure.php on line 410
PHP Warning:  /persistent/ is not writable in /home/ezra/sites/example.nl/cake/libs/cache/file.php on line 267

Warning: /persistent/ is not writable in /home/ezra/sites/example.nl/cake/libs/cache/file.php on line 267
PHP Warning:  /models/ is not writable in /home/ezra/sites/example.nl/cake/libs/cache/file.php on line 267

Warning: /models/ is not writable in /home/ezra/sites/example.nl/cake/libs/cache/file.php on line 267

Welcome to CakePHP v1.3.10 Console
```

And my Cache::config in core.php

```
/*
  Memcached (http://www.danga.com/memcached/)
 */
     Cache::config('default', array(
        'engine' => 'Memcached', //[required]
        'duration'=> 3600, //[optional]
        'probability'=> 100, //[optional]
        'prefix' => 'smm_', //[optional]  prefix every cache file with this string
        'servers' => array(
            array('127.0.0.1', 11211), // localhost, default port 11211
        ), //[optional]
        'compress' => true, // [optional] compress data in Memcache (slower, but uses less memory)
        'persistent' => false, // [optional] set this to false for non-persistent connections
    ));
```

Are there any bugs with Shells and custom cacheengines or did I really mess up?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

I had a different php.ini for cli, in this php.ini I forgot to load the memcached.so.

After adding this to the php.ini it worked fine!